# Uploading in React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6

I'm uploading multiples images and I wanted to display the correct percentage "50%".
However I'm calling the API one by one. Meaning I upload the image one by one.

The problem is the percentage keeps getting back and forth like 0 - 50%, then going back again to 0 and so on... The reason for this is because I'm dispatching the `setProgress` multiples times.

What will be the correct calculation to achieve the correct percentage?

**Reducer**

```
case SET_UPLOAD_PROGRESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    uploadProgress: action.payload,
  }
```

**Actions**

```
export const uploadImages =
  ({ images }) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    images.forEach(async (image) => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append(image.name, image.imageFile);

      try {
        dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGES_REQUEST });

        const response = await axios.post("http://test.com", formData, {
          onUploadProgress(progressEvent) {
            const { loaded, total } = progressEvent;
            const percentage = Math.floor((loaded / total) * 100);

            dispatch(setUploadProgress(percentage));   <- GETTING PERCENTAGE. IT IS WORKING ALREADY. EXAMPLE OUTPUT: 50
          },
        });

        dispatch({
          type: UPLOAD_IMAGES_SUCCESS,
          payload: [...(images || [])],
        });
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGES_FAILURE });
      }
    });
  };
```

**Component**

```
   const uploadProgress = useSelector(state => state.images.uploadProgress);

    <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={uploadProgress} />
```

Answer (score 1):

[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) can handle multiple files, even under the same field name. If the API supports it, build up your request payload and send it once

```js
export const uploadImages =
  ({ images }) =>
  async (dispatch) => { // async here
    const formData = new FormData();
    images.forEach(image => {
      formData.append(image.name, image.imageFile);
    })

    // as per usual from here...
  };
```

Otherwise, you'll need to chunk the progress by the number of images, treating the average as the total progress.

```js
export const uploadImages =
  ({ images }) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    const imageCount = images.length;
    const chunks = Array.from({ length: imageCount }, () => 0);

    await Promise.all(images.map(async (image, index) => {
      // snip...

      await axios.post(url, formData, {
        onUploadProgress({ loaded, total }) {
          // for debugging
          console.log(
            "chunk:", index,
            "loaded:", loaded,
            "total:", total,
            "ratio:", loaded / total
          );

          // store this chunk's progress ratio
          chunks[index] = loaded / total;
    
          // the average of chunks represents the total progress
          const avg = chunks.reduce((sum, p) => sum + p, 0) / chunks.length;

          dispatch(setUploadProgress(Math.floor(avg * 100)));
        }
      });

      // snip...
    });
    
    // snip...
  };
```

Note that the upload progress can reach 100% before the request actually completes. To handle that, you may want something in your store that detects when the `uploadProgress` is set to 100 and set another state (`finalisingUpload = true` for example) that you can clear after the request complete.

Here's a quick demo using mocks showing how the logic works ~ https://jsfiddle.net/rtLvxkb2/

Comment: Hi Phil. I'm getting more than 100 with your second answer

Comment: Haha thanks Phil. My api doesn't support your first answer. Just use your second answer

Comment: Hi Phil. It currently outputs 100 instantly without having to wait for the API response to finish

Comment: @Joseph that seems odd. I've tested this now and it works for me as expected

Comment: Did you upload a lot of images?

Comment: I just used an Axios mock to simulate the uploads. The logic here works. If something else is wrong, you might need to do some debugging, eg `console.log("chunk:", index, "loaded:", loaded, "total:", total, "ratio:", loaded / total);`

Comment: I think this is a known issue here https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2709. Might there be a hack?

Comment: Axios just uses the underlying [XMLHttpRequest: progress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/progress_event). Note that if you're uploading to `localhost` it can be very fast. You may need another state in your store like "finalising upload" or something to handle the time between 100% progress and when the request is complete

Comment: Can you add that too in your answer? Btw, The backend is already online while the frontend is on localhost

Comment: This one  "You may need another state in your store like "finalising upload" or something to handle the time between 100% progress and when the request is complete"

Comment: @Joseph if you're after an actual implementation, that's straying a little too far from the original question and I'd need to see more of your redux store to hint at a solution

Comment: Ok. I'll just get back to you then

Comment: @Joseph I added a note to my answer but it's reasonably generic

Comment: Ok, Thanks Phil